# Константные методы

Tags: c++

Просветите, пожалуйста, на тему константных методов в C++; зачем нужны, в чем преимущества?! С небольшими примерами кода, если не затруднит.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Константные методы служат для определения того, что можно сделать с классом без побочного действия на его состояние, и что изменяет его состояние. Пользователю класса, в котором правильно расставлены `const`, в некоторых случаях, например, удаётся избежать лишнего копирования объектов без потери данных. Также при правильном использовании `const` на уровне компиляции исключается случайное изменение объекта в методе, который не должен ничего в объекте менять. Например, есть класс типа

```
class A
{
  int a;
  int b;
  public:
  int getA() { b = b + 1;return a; }
  int getB() { a = a + 1;return b; }
};
```

Здесь мнемоника и семантика немного несоответствуют. Вот хочется думать, что если

```
A x, y;
...
bool f = x.getA() == y.getA() && x.getB() == y.getB();
```

`f` истина, то `x` и `y` в чём-то похожи, но внутренности класса реализованы не так. Пользователь класса должен быть уверен, что геттер ничего не испортит. Хороший разработчик класса должен явно описывать характер поведения метода с помощью `const` или отсутствия `const`

```
class A
{
  int a;
  int b;
  public:
  int getA() const { return a; }
  int getB() const { return b; }
};
```

Но если вам вдруг понадобится делать прогу, в которой есть что-то вроде подсчёта обращений к переменной, то семантика геттеров заставляет употребить `const`, но счётчик обращений нужно увеличивать. Для этого случая есть слово `mutable`! Этим словом мы пометим поля, которые вроде как бы члены класса, но они не отражают что ли его состояние

```
class A
{
  int a;
  int b;
  mutable int cntA;
  mutable int cntB;
  public:
  int getA() const { cntA++; return a; }
  int getB() const { cntB++; return b; }
};
```

Comment: mutable и const представляют собой прекрасный пример искусственных трудностей языка C++.
И вообще - использование getter'ов и setter'ов не лучший тон. В том плане, что их не нужно делать на любую переменную внутри класса. Уж лучше ясные функции, которые делают само действие, чтобы логика работы была внутри класса. К тому же, часть параметров можно задавать при конструировании объекта (экземпляра класса). Вот как-то так.

Comment: Геттер - это один пример использования. Можно придумать другие. Язык C++ может быть использован для создания искусственных трудностей - это бесспорно. В этом опасность любого мощного инструментария.

Answer (score 4):

Несколько слов о применении константных методов.
Классы с константными методами удобно применять:

1.Когда над проектом работают несколько программистов.
  Когда проектируется класс разработчик сразу определяет, что и при каких условиях может меняться, а что должно остаться неизменным. Константные классы тут как раз к месту для построения всех "запретительных заборов", чтобы другой разработчик случайно не изменил состояние объекта.
Как правило, классы с константными методами не имеют конструктор по умолчанию, а только конструкторы, зависящие от каких-то объектов. Это очень удобно, так как все члены будут инициализированы. Кстати, это единственный способ инициализации константных членов.

2.Использование объектов const.
Если создается константный объект, то для обращения к его методам и членам надо использовать константные методы. Например, если в функцию передается указатель на объект, но хочется обезопасить его от изменения, то нужно его объявлять как const

Answer (score 4):

В нестатические методы класса компилятор неявно передаёт константный указатель на объект от которого был вызван метод, его сигнатура

```
T* const this   // адресс на который указывает this поменять нельзя
```

благодаря ему можно связать обращение к переменным и методам с фактическим адрессом экземпляра. Следовательно код:

```
void f()
{
   m_a = 10;
}
```

эквивалентен

```
void f()
{
   this->m_a = 10;
}
```

В случаи с константными методами, вы меняем два поведения:

1. Теперь данный метод может быть вызван для константного объекта.

   ```
   const Foo a;
   a->f();         // only if f() is const method
   ```
2. Теперь внутрь данных методов передаётся константный указатель на константу.

   ```
   const T* const this;  // адресс и состояние объекта на который указывает this поменять нельзя
   ```

следовательно

```
void f()
{
   this->m_a = 10; // ошибка нельзя менять состояние константного объекта
}
```

---

Преймущества константного метода:

1. можно вызывать для константных объектов и указателей на константу.
2. применения `grammar const` (всё что должно быть const - должно иметь данный спецификатор) - если метод не меняет объект то почему бы программисту явно не указать это себе, другим программистам и компилятору?
3. Можно перегрузить метод через его константность:

   ```
   struct Array
   {
       int x;
       int operator[]( int index ) const
       {
           return x;
       }
       int& operator[]( int index )
       {
           return x;
       }
   };

   int main()
   {
       Array a;
       a[1] = 10;          //  int& operator[]( int index )
                           //  ok
       const Array b;
       b[1] = 10;          //  int operator[]( int index ) const
                           //  error: `int` is not lvalue
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Константный метод, это такой метод который не меняет сам класс, при попытке откомпилировать код, который содержит константную функцию меняет класс компилятор выдаст ошибку, у константных классов могут быть вызваны только константные методы.

Comment: то есть , я так понимаю, они не могут изменить ничего в том классе , в котором они определены?!

Comment: кроме mutable членов класса

Comment: зато могут что-то рассказать о том, что есть в классе, в котором они определены

Answer (score 1):

Все становится понятно если разобраться как "работают" методы классов.

```
class A {
public:
 int GetSome();
 void SetSome(int some);
}
```

Для компилятора любой вызова метода класса по сути выглядит вот так:

```
int GetSome(const A* const this);
void SetSome(A* const this,int some);
```

Из чего очевидно, что при попытке изменить константный объект, вы получите по рукам.
И из этого становится понятно, почему дружественные функции, статические функции не могут быть константными.

Comment: а где бы почитать про то как для компилятора все "выглядит"?? то есть как компилятор работает с кодом?

Comment: В стандарте.

Comment: С чего бы, если ты не поставил `const?

Answer (score 0):

А теперь на русском:

> Константный метод, это такой метод, который не меняет свойств/членов класса.
> При попытке откомпилировать код, который содержит константный метод изменяющий класс - компилятор выдаст ошибку.
> У константных объектов, могут быть вызваны только константные методы.

Константных функций небывает. Как и константных классов ;)

Comment: эксперт имел в виду скорее всего константы-объекты_класса

Comment: я то догадался, а вот ТС - не факт.

Comment: то есть если я хочу чтобы данный метод не менял "состояние " моего класса, тогда указываю константный метод? типа чтобы компилятор выбрасывал ексепшн , если вдруг оно изменится на этапе компиляции??

Comment: да, специфицируешь его как константный.
но если тело метода вдруг попытается изменить свойства класса, то никакого exception`а выброшено не будет. получишь ошибку компиляции.

Answer (score 0):

Очень хорошо все объяснено в книжке Джефф Элджер. С++: Библиотека программиста - СПб: Издательство "Питер", 2000.
Если можно, то могу здесь привести цитату из нее.

Comment: Не можно, а нужно.