# Ссылки и указатели в константных методах класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, ссылки, const

Сразу оставлю ссылку, где задаётся примерно такой же вопрос, может быть будет кому полезно [статья](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/9318/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b).

Вопрос по следующему коду:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using std::endl;
using std::cout;

struct S{

    char arr[10];
    
    const char& operator[](size_t index) const{

        return arr[index];
    }

};

struct C{
    
    int x = 12;
    
    int* z = &x;

    int& y = x;

    void foo() const{

        ++y;

        ++*z;
    }
};

int main(){
   
   const C c;

   c.foo(); 

   cout<<c.x<<endl;
        
}
```

В этом примере у нас есть 2 класса с константными методами, я хочу разобраться как работает константность в методах. Правильно ли я понимаю, что в случае класса `S` внутри константного метода константность накладывается именно на `char` и мы получаем `const char` и именно поэтому мы должны писать `const char` в возвращаемом типе данного метода, так как иначе сбросится константность.

Следующий вопрос: почему в структуре `C` у меня получается изменить константное поле `const int c` внутри константного метода через ссылку/указатель, разве это не `UB`???
Я пытаюсь понять логику константных методов, помогите, пожалуйста, прояснить ситуацию.
Единственное объяснение, которое я здесь нашел - в константных методах константность распространяется как бы только на имена полей: то есть я не могу напрямую через обращение по именам менять поля, однако зависимости в виде наличия ссылок сохраняются.

Comment: Внутри метода константность накладывается при обращении к объекту, на который указывает `this`, то бишь получается обращение к `S const`. *"константное поле const int c"* - в коде такого нет. UB было бы изменение объекта, который был создан с const-квалификатором `C const c{};`.

Comment: менять вы не можете указатель `z` и ссылку `y`. А объекты куда они указывали - можно. *переменную `c` - не нашёл.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае константного метода весь объект (кроме `mutable`-членов) является константным. Поэтому ваш `arr` из-за этого в константном методе является константным, и вы просто не можете возвращать неконстантную ссылку — тем самым предоставляя механизм для изменения константного объекта.

Во втором случае имеется косвенность, которая и мешает определиться. Кто знает, куда там во время выполнения указывают `z` и `y`? Ведь можно переписать код так, что они будут указывать не на `x`. Так что вы изменить не можете само значение `z`, а вот то, на что оно указывает...

Вот пример (все остальное остается, как у вас):

```
int main()
{
    int v = 1;
    C c{12,&v,v};
    c.foo();
    cout<<c.x<<endl;
    cout<<v<<endl;
}
```

Компилятор не настолько умен, чтобы суметь понять, куда указывает `z` и на что ссылается `y`...

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Почему тогда, если рассматривать ссылки на константы вне контекста классов, то мне запрещено делать вот так:

int main(){
   
    const int x = 12;

    int* ptr =& x;  
    //int& a = x;
}

Ну то есть компилятор видит, что я пытаюсь получить доступ к константному объекту через ссылку на не константу(или указатель на не константу), и далее запрещает мне это сделать, так как я сбрасываю `const`, но при этом в полях класса такой же логики не наблюдается, вот это-то мне и не понятно почему.

Comment: Потому что здесь *компилятор* видит, что `x` — константная переменная. Но для `foo` это совершенно не видно на уровне *компиляции*. Вы же в `foo` не пытаетесь присвоить `z` адрес `x`? Добавьте в `foo` строку `z = &x;` и убедитесь, что такой код скомпилировать не получится.